# ConstraintLayout margins

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a simple layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorDarkGray">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:alpha="0.7"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:letterSpacing="0.03"
            android:text="Another text"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:letterSpacing="0.03"
            android:text="Some text"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In design view, it looks so [image: looks so]
As you can see there is no left and right margins. Top and bottom margins work well. If I remove left or right margin my relative layout moves beyond the screen a bit.
Guess I can do it without a relative layout at all, BUT I'm interested why that happened.

Comment: Just set RelativeLayout width to match parent (0dp)

Comment: This happens to cause you align the textView to parent right and left and your RelativeLayout is wrap_content

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this change your `RelativeLayout` width to **`android:layout_width="0dp"`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorDarkGray">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:alpha="0.7"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:letterSpacing="0.03"
            android:text="Another text"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:letterSpacing="0.03"
            android:text="Some text"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: ConstraintLayout doesn't get match_parent. you have to set width to "0dp"

Comment: This feels like it defeats the purpose of Constrain Layout

Answer (score 18):

You should avoid using nested views inside ConstraintLayout. The reasons are:

- ConstraintLayout allows you to create large and complex layouts with a flat view hierarchy (no nested view groups) as it's stated in [Build a Responsive UI with ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)
- Traditional nested layout hierarchy negatively impacts on performance as it's stated in [Understanding the performance benefits of ConstraintLayout](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/understanding-performance-benefits-of.html)

The result layout source should look like:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorDarkGray">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:letterSpacing="0.03"
        android:text="Another text"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:letterSpacing="0.03"
        android:text="Some text"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Result view]

You can learn how to build layouts with ConstraintLayouts by following steps in [Google's Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/#0).

Comment: Thanks for that, android:layout_width="0dp" and android:layout_height="wrap_content" (on the TextView) solved my problem of a TextView inside a ConstraintLayout expanding to fill the width ignoring its margins. Do you know where that's documented?

Comment: @Ewan Perhaps it's documented here https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/#adjust-the-view-size

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course there're no left and right margins in your layout when you're defining your `RelativeLayout` as below:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

That means `RelativeLayout` has `wrap_content` width and height and it's in the center of `Parent` (with our constraintTop,Bot....).

How to solve it? Just set the `width` of your relative layout to `0dp`. According to `constraints`, that means your `RelativeLayout` will be as wide as parent.